# Which is the best Android tool to visualize JPG+JGW images?

Tags: mobile, android, jpg

I've got some georeferenced JPG+JGW images, and would like to visualize them on my Android device. Which is, in your opinion, the best tool?

I've tried OSMdroid (after converting JPG+JGW with MapTiler), but I can't create points to mark some places. Are other alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

[QGIS also has an android port](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/android-qgis), so I suggest you give that a try. During this year's GSOC, it is being improved even further for a more native feel. It requires at least android 2.3 and isn't as resource efficient as a dedicated solution would be though.

Answer (score 0):

DogSheep Customizable Maps lets you overlay JPG images on top of the map. It will place the image according to the GPS tag in the JPG, but you may have to adjust the JPG image within the app to position it exactly. DogSheep can also let you create points to mark places on the map.